# Angular router navigate perform before previous code lines

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8, angular-router

I'm facing a strange behavior with my angular code.
I have a login page that calls an API.

login.component.ts:

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formData;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formData = new FormGroup({
      login: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  onClickSubmit(data) {
    this.usersService.login(data).subscribe((response) => {
      const token = response.token;
      const userLogin = response.user.userLogin;

      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('login', userLogin);

      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```html
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Login
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(formData.value)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputLogin">Login</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" name="login" placeholder="Login" formControlName="login">
          <span *ngIf="(login.dirty || login.touched) && login.invalid && login.errors.required" class="error">Login is required</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
          <span *ngIf="(password.dirty || password.touched) && password.invalid && password.errors.required" class="error">Login is required</span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formData.valid">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text login-text"><small class="text-muted">Don't have any account? <a routerLink="/register">Register</a></small></p>
  </div>
```

I noticed that `this.router.navigate()` is performed before my `localStorage.setIem`.

users.service.ts:

```js
export class UsersService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://localhost:63939/api/v1/';
  private registerUrl = this.apiUrl + 'identity/register';
  private loginUrl = this.apiUrl + 'identity/login';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  register(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<AuthResponse>(this.registerUrl, user);
  }

  login(user: LoginRequest): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<AuthResponse>(this.loginUrl, user);
  }
}
```

menu.component.ts:

```js
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  showLoginLink = true;
  userLogin;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userLogin = localStorage.getItem('login');
    if (this.userLogin !== null) {
      this.showLoginLink = false;
    }
  }

}
```

menu.component.html

```html
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="showLoginLink">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/register">Login / Register</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="userLogin">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/register">{{userLogin}}</a>
</li>
```

When the navigate is performed, the menu is displayed but localStorage is empty so my userLogin is null and my `*ngIf="userLogin"` does not work. localStorage is filled right after the redirect, if I refresh the page, I've my values and my menu works (display my second `<li>` instead of the first).

Is it a standard behavior? How I can achieve the menu changes without refresh my page?
(I prefer an explanation rather than a ready-made solution but I don't' refuse a solution ^-^)

**EDIT**: Add some code due to comments :) I will edit again if more code is needed

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] of your issue, so that we can see what you have tried, and tell you what's wrong (if any).

Comment: Try logging the `localStorage.getItem('login')` right before `router.navigate()` and in the `onInit()` method of `menu.component`. The issue looks kinda strange because `localStorage.setItem()` calls are *synchronous* meaning that `router.navigate` will not be executed earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because your navigate to home component and "menu" component is loaded before login component.

You can use observer to let menu component know that login preformed.

First of all you will make a service let's call it AuthService

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public loginPreformedObserver: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
}
```

then in your login component

```
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    formData;

    constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private router: 
    Router,private authService: AuthService) 
    { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.formData = new FormGroup({
      login: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
     });
    }

    onClickSubmit(data) {
      this.usersService.login(data).subscribe((response) => {
      const token = response.token;
      const userLogin = response.user.userLogin;

      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('login', userLogin);
      this.authService.loginPreformedObserver.next();
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      });
      }
}
```

then in your menu component

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  showLoginLink = true;
  userLogin;
  private _loginPreformed: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._loginPreformed= this.authService.loginPreformedObserver;
    this._loginPreformed.subscribe(
     value => 
        {
      this.userLogin = localStorage.getItem('login');
      if (this.userLogin !== null) 
      {
        this.showLoginLink = false;
      }
        });

  }

}
```

For more details please see this [link](https://medium.com/instarem-engineering/subjects-in-angular-2-4-5-4e5986e38e47)

Comment: I like the idea, do you have some link that explains it and/or show how to do?

Comment: I tried to do the same with a disconnect method but apparently I don't understand how observers work. Is there a way to discuss it with you (out of this thread)?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because  `ngOnInit` was called once  before  `onClickSubmit` triggered. So `userLogin` won't updated.

You need somehow  notify `MenuComponent` that `userLogin` value already changed

Answer (score 0):

It happens because writing data in the local storage takes an amount of time, so your navigation is performed before that the data is available and can be retrieved.
You can avoid this by setting a timeout before navigating to the '/home' route or by adding attributes inside the usersService so values will be immediately available after a successful login.